# sum of specific columns in matrices

Tags: r, dplyr

I have several matrices which have different values in first column and second column and same values in the third one, I would like to sum them and the result matrix to consist of first column and second column that is sum of matrices and no operation should be done with the third column.

```
a<-matrix(1:9,3,3)
b<-matrix(c(2:7,7,8,9),3,3)
c<-matrix(c(3:8,7,8,9),3,3)
```

result matrix:

```
d<-matrix(c(6,9,12,15,18,21,7,8,9),3,3)
d
```

Any idea on how I should proceed with this?
I tagged dplyr because I think the answer might lie there, but base R answers are also more than welcome.

Comment: Which approach have you tried so far and where does it fail?

Comment: You can simply add the matrices and replace the 3rd column with 3rd column from any one of the input matrix

Comment: @matt_jay, I tried simple stuff like d<-sum(a+b+c, ncol=1,2), but the result is the sum of all numbers in the matrices, I have honestly no idea on how to proceed with this.

Comment: @Mohan Govindasamy, yeah, it would work for this oversimplified example, problem is, matrices in my data contain strings in the latter columns. :)

Comment: Does the answer provided by @sindri_baldur works for the above case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d2 <- cbind((a+b+c)[, -3], c[, 3])
all.equal(d, d2) # TRUE
```

NB. It is not good practice to name an object `c` in R.